# Thymeleaf builder object

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

As far as I understood I need an object in order to submit forms with Thymeleaf. But what if I have an object which is supposed to be created with builder inner class? Is there a workaround for that or  do I have to create a separated class with the same fields as builder object has?

Upd:
So, the template I want to use is this

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Sign up form</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<h1>Input user data</h1>
<!--/*@thymesVar id="user" type="com.university.domain.User"*/-->
<form action="#" th:action="@{/register}" th:object="${user}" method="post">
    <p>Id: <input type="text" th:field="*{id}" /></p>
    <p>E-mail: <input type="text" th:field="*{email}" /></p>
    <p>Password: <input type="text" th:field="*{password}" /></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" /></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And the user I want to create is this one

```java
package com.university.domain;

import java.util.Objects;

public class User {
    protected final Integer id;
    protected final String email;
    protected final String password;
    protected final String firstName;
    protected final String lastName;
    protected final Role role;

    protected User(UserBuilder<? extends UserBuilder> userUserBuilder) {

        this.id = userUserBuilder.id;
        this.email = userUserBuilder.email;
        this.password = userUserBuilder.password;
        this.firstName = userUserBuilder.firstName;
        this.lastName = userUserBuilder.lastName;
        this.role = userUserBuilder.role;
    }

    public static UserBuilder<? extends UserBuilder> builder() {
        return new UserBuilder();
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public Role getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        User user = (User) o;
        return Objects.equals(id, user.id) &&
                Objects.equals(firstName, user.firstName) &&
                Objects.equals(lastName, user.lastName);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id, firstName, lastName);
    }

    public static class UserBuilder<SELF extends UserBuilder<SELF>> {

        protected Integer id;
        protected String email;
        protected String password;
        protected String firstName;
        protected String lastName;
        protected Role role;

        protected UserBuilder() {
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public SELF self() {
            return (SELF) this;
        }

        public User build() {
            return new User(self());
        }

        public SELF withId(Integer id) {
            this.id = id;
            return self();
        }

        public SELF withFirstName(String firstName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
            return self();
        }

        public SELF withLastName(String lastName) {
            this.lastName = lastName;
            return self();
        }

        public SELF withEmail(String email) {
            this.email = email;
            return self();
        }

        public SELF withPassword(String password) {
            this.password = password;
            return self();
        }

        public SELF withRole(Role role) {
            this.role = role;
            return self();
        }
    }
}
```

I don't have set methods in user class, so I'm not sure thymeleaf will handle it.

Comment: Can you provide the relevant Java code and Thymeleaf template? What framework (if any) are you using? Everything needed to render and populate a Thymeleaf template is typically passed to the renderer using a `Map`. There is no reason why a builder would prevent that.

Comment: I have updated the question, and I'm using Spring Boot to run all of this.

Comment: You should probably add a Spring Boot tag to your question.  I use Thymeleaf - but I don't use Spring.

Comment: But would it work out with plain Thymeleaf?

Comment: The fact that your bean does not have any setters (only public getters) will not stop Thymeleaf from using it.  Have you tried using your bean in Spring Boot?  If so, what happened?

Comment: It fails with this error `No primary or default constructor found for class com.university.domain.User`, basically I think without public plain constructor thymeleaf can't do anything with the object I'm trying to use

Comment: I see your point.  And adding `public User(){}` would undermine some (but not all?) of the benefits of having a builder.

Comment: Well, I decided to work it around with form class consisting only of fields, getters and setters and it went fine.